# Digital Sum and Sort Implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, data-structures

I am given a = [13, 20, 7, 4] array of integers and I am trying to write a digitalsumandsort(a) = [20, 4, 13, 7] function as shown. If two numbers have the same sum of digits, the smaller one (in the regular sense) should come first. 4 and 13 have the same sum of digits, however 4 < 13 thus 4 comes before 13 in any digitalsumandsort sorting where both are present. But I can only sort the sum of the digits not the numbers. Hash function will be perfect for this problem but I am trying to solve this with just using array of integers. Here is my code and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
std::vector<int> digitalsumandsort(std::vector<int> a) {
    std::vector<int> result;
    int sum=0;
    int max=999;
    int temp;
    for (int i=0; i<a.size();i++){
        temp=a[i];
        while(temp>0){
            sum+=temp%10;
            temp/=10;
        }
        result.push_back(sum);
        sum=0;    
    }
    std::sort(result.begin(),result.begin()+4);
    return result;
}
```

Input:
a: [13, 20, 7, 4]
Output:
[2, 4, 4, 7]
Expected Output:
[20, 4, 13, 7]

Comment: You sort and return `result`. `result` contains the sums. You want gather the sums, sort `a` according to the sums and return the sorted `a`. Consider a `vector<pair<int,int>` that contains pairs the digital sum and source number or specify a custom comparator that computes the digital sum on the fly, then sort st the source number according to the digital sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply a custom comparator to the sort function.

```
std::vector<int> initial_values = {13, 20, 4, 7};
std::vector<int> sorted_values = initial_values;
std::sort(sorted_values.begin(), sorted_values.end(), [](const int & a, const int & b) {
    int a_temp = a, b_temp = b;
    int a_sum = 0, b_sum = 0;
    while(a_temp != 0) {
        a_sum += a_temp % 10;
        a_temp /= 10;
    }
    while(b_temp != 0) {
        b_sum += b_temp % 10;
        b_temp /= 10;
    }
    if(a_sum != b_sum) return a_sum < b_sum;
    else return a <= b;
});

print_contents_of_vector(initial_values);
print_contents_of_vector(sorted_values);
```

Output:

```
{13, 20, 4, 7} //From initial value printing
{20, 4, 13, 7} //From sorted value printing
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Xirema

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this. Use comparator for the sort function as follows. Here is the [link](http://ideone.com/oPbQ7S).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int sum_digits(int a ) {
    int sum=0;
    while(a!=0) {
        sum += a%10;
        a /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

struct Comparator {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) {
        int sum_digits_a = sum_digits(a);
        int sum_digits_b = sum_digits(b);

        if(sum_digits_a == sum_digits_b)
            return a < b;
        return sum_digits_a < sum_digits_b;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<int> vec{13, 20, 7, 4};  
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Comparator() );

    for(auto v : vec)
        cout << v << " ";
    return 0;
}
```